# Mysql query with multiple year intervals

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

I have created a few drop down boxes that allow users to narrow down the data they are looking for. Two of the drop down boxes involve where the users select years. For example, the first box could be 1990, and the second box could be 2000. Now how to I set up a query that allows this interval of time to be applied?

```
$pYear1 = the first year they select in the drop down box 
$pYear2 = the second year they select in the drop down box 

select * from table where year = '$pYear1 - $pYear2';
```

I tried this but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `WHERE year BETWEEN $pYear1 AND $pYear2`? [BETWEEN ... AND ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: I have the strong feeling this is calling for SQL Injection. You should never ever directly inject user provided values in an SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `BETWEEN`

```
select * from table where year BETWEEN '$pYear1' AND '$pYear2';
```

UPDATE:

As @SylvainLeroux suggested, it is highly recommended to use pdo or mysqli for performance and security reasons:

[PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[MySQLi Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux you are right :), but the question wasn't security related. user2562125 should use PDO or MySQLI for preventing sql injections

Comment: This is the frustrating part of SO: answering the question is sometime like giving the OP a gun to shoot him(her)self in the foot. But you are right: I should have post my comment about security on the question, not on your answer ;)

Comment: After all we are trying to help the OP, so i will reference the documentation for PDO and mysqli as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

As I noticed in a comment, you should never ever directly inject user provided values in an SQL query.

As you are using PHP, the preferred way of doing is probably to use a prepared statement. Here I use PDO (assuming your "years" are integers):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('* from table where year BETWEEN :start_year AND :end_year;');
$sth->bindParam(':start_year', $pYear1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':end_year', $pYear2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

This is only an example. Several variations are available. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Is PDO required for security? I don't know much about PDO.

Comment: @user2562125 Our main concern here was, using the `$pYear1` notation you insert _untrusted_ data in the query you send to the DB. Possibly resulting in [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Using a _prepared statement_ will prevent this notably by "shielding" special characters -- and so ensuring that placeholders could only store _values_ (and not arbitrary SQL). For security reasons, any library providing such mechanism will be useful. As of PDO, this is  "just" one such library.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want the range excluding the date you can just do this.

```
select * from table where year > '$pYear1' and year < '$pYear2';
```